# How to efficiently send personalized notification to 10k users using FCM

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM gives two options to send notifications:

- [to] - takes one gcm token
- [registration_ids] - takes array of 1000 gcm token

So, If I had to send message to 10k users then using registration_ids it will take 10 request to fcm server. But the message is same for every request. I can change message every time in case of to but then i will have to send 10k different requests.

Now, I want to send personalized message.

eg: registration_ids[0]='ggggss' his name is alpha. I would want to send hey alpha,.... similarly for every user.

Is there a way to send personalized notification efficiently?

example syntax: **curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=" \
    --Header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
    -d "{\"to\":\"\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Yellow\"},\"priority\":10}"**

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in mail merge functionality in Firebase Cloud Message (as far as I know). You will either have to send the same message to multiple users, or perform a separate API call for each user